# How to implement multilanguage form in antd properly?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a form where the user can enter text in the fields, and then select from a dropdown to change the language and fill the same form in the newly chosen language. I can't have a flag for the language and reset the fields because I need to submit the form in every language that is entered. Is there a standard way to implement this with antd? Thanks.

Comment: write some code or show some sandbox, then ask how to implement it with an antd.

Answer (score 0):

Antd will help you with the design, by providing you with out-of-the-box components such as forms, dropdowns or tabs.

But you will have to implement the logic yourself. One way to do it would be to store the content of the current form in the state, with the language as the key. Then on language update you have a callback that validates the form and insert the current answers into the state. In the end, you will have a form with answers for multiple languages and you send that to your backend on submit.